# Can you name the Country Code™? (#2)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, geography, letters

Given the country codes of 10 countries in the chart below, can you figure out the country code of Brazil?

| Country | Country Code™ |
| --- | --- |
| Russia | NSR |
| Sudan | GDA |
| United States | BIE |
| Argentina | EGS |
| Mongolia | BNM |
| Chile | CIS |
| South Korea | AUK |
| Mexico | CXS |
| United Kingdom | AIE |
| Italy | FAI |
| Brazil | ??? |

CSV version:

```
Country,             Country Code™
Russia,              NSR
Sudan,               GDA
United States,       BIE
Argentina,           EGS
Mongolia,            BNM
Chile,               CIS
South Korea,         AUK
Mexico,              CXS
United Kingdom,      AIE
Italy,               FAI
Brazil,              ???
```

<sup>Related question (solved independently): [Can you name the Country Code™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97581/can-you-name-the-country-code)</sup>

Comment: oh it's brazil again ahaha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This time, the country code of Brazil is:

> **JAP**

This is because:

> The first letter of each code is the letter in the alphabetical position (i.e. A1Z26) corresponding to the number of neighbouring countries on a map - for Brazil (10 neighbours: Argentina, Bolivia, Colombia, French Guiana, Guyana, Paraguay, Peru, Suriname, Uruguay, and Venezuela), this is the 10th letter of the alphabet, **J**.
>
>  The second letter of each code is the third letter of the country's name, as written in this list - for Brazil, this is **A**.
>
>  The third letter of the code is the first letter of the language chiefly spoken within that country - for Brazil this is **P**ortuguese, hence **P**.

For a full explanation for each country in the original list, see the following table:

> [image]

Comment: You're too quick :P

Comment: argh! I got the last two letters already, but just got stumped by the first; well done

Comment: Wow, that was really fast! I have to wait 5 minutes to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @oAlt same :) Stiv just doesn't know the meaning of stumped :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Sorry guys! Geography's definitely my specialist subject - I even once confessed my love for it on national TV! :)

Comment: @oAlt Thanks, the giveaway for me on the first one was spotting that the UK and South Korea had the same letter, and then that Mongolia and the US did too, one further along than the others...