# What is the Color Code™?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, cipher, number-property

<sub>Inspired from [Can you name the country code?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97629/51928) and [What is a Number™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series</sub>

---

$
\begin{gather}
% custom template - reuse if you may
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{21px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\color{white}{\textbf{ Number }}}\def\NT{\color{white}{\textbf{ Color Code}^{™}}}\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[maroon]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2020.01.21-custom}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\T&\NT\\\hline
%
~\text{ 0 }&\color{green}{ Green }\\ \hline
~\text{ 1 }&\color{indigo}{ Indigo }\\ \hline
~\text{ $\varphi$ }&\text{ ? }\\ \hline
~\text{ 2 }&\color{violet}{ Violet }\\ \hline
~\text{ $e$ }&\color{Orange}{ Orange }\\ \hline
~\text{ 3 }&\color{Indigo}{ Indigo }\\ \hline
~\text{ $\pi$ }&\color{Orange}{ Orange }\\ \hline
~\text{ 4 }&\color{red}{ Red }\\ \hline
~\text{ 5 }&\color{orange}{ Orange }\\ \hline
~\text{ 6 }&\color{green}{ Green }\\ \hline
~\text{ 7 }&\color{yellow}{ Yellow }\\ \hline
~\text{ 8 }&\color{green}{ Green }\\ \hline
~\text{ 9 }&\color{Indigo}{ Indigo }\\ \hline
~\text{ 17 }&\color{orange}{ Orange }\\ \hline
~\text{ 42 }&\text{ ? }\\ \hline
\end{array}\end{gather}$

### 3 Questions for this puzzle

1. What is the Color code of [$\varphi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)?
2. What is the Color code of 42?
3. What is the smallest integer number to be $\color{Blue}{Blue}$?

## Hint A.1 - 17th May

> First reasonable step to resolution is to spell out in English each integer or constant

## Hint B - 20th May

> All possible color codes are given in the puzzle

## Hint A.2 - 26th May

Extending hint A.1.

> You will need the number of letters of each integer or constant spell out in English.

## Hint C - 21th June

> You will need to find the appropriate sort on all colors.

## Hint D - 24th June

I'm adding an hint earlier than I planned as a bounty was given.

> The overall cryptography scheme is:
>
>  Sort colors like Hint C and select a given number $x$.
>  **1.** Spell out $x$ like Hint A and save the number of letters $n$.
>  **2.** Apply a cryptography function which needs $n$, $x$ and the appropriate sort on colors.
>  **3.** Output of cryptography function is $x$'s color code.
>
>  Note that our cryptography function is really simple, in my opinion, nearly all undergraduate students would understand it, but not find it necessarily as you've guessed it :)

Comment: Start points seems like it is a 3 number problem with RGB components. R and G components take only 3 values whereas B only take 2

Comment: Do you acknowledge the existence of indigo?  Seems potentially pertinent, given the question about red.

Comment: @BenBarden, I can't believe I missed that... Thanks!

Comment: Is 17 to be orange or yellow?

Comment: I feel like it should be possible for us to leverage the fact that we have the versions both with and without indigo thanks to the edit history, but I'll admit that I'm still quite lost.  Perhaps, when the time comes, you could formalize that as your first clue.  :)

Comment: Hmm... The puzzle changed a lot from the first time I saw this, didn't it... Should I scrap my old note? Or are both fine as the solving paths are same?

Comment: @BenBarden, yes! That could be an idea for a clue. However, I suggest you to focus on the last version

Comment: @athin, I suggest you to focus on the last version. For your notes, I think you can apply them to the current puzzle :)

Comment: Are colors limited to ROY G BIV, or are others (Black, White, Cyan) possible?

Comment: @dan04, maybe I'll answer in the next hint?

Comment: I think it is time for next hint :P

Comment: @dan04, last hint answers your question :)

Comment: @SagarChand, no sooner said than done!

Comment: Got any more of those juicy hints? I'm lost.

Comment: One more hint Please?

Comment: @Ankit, a bit late, but done!

Comment: In case someone haven't noticed yet, the possible color codes are the rot13(pbybef bs gur envaobj). Unfortunately I don't have much more to post an answer

Comment: Are 6 and 17 correct?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, I have re-check and you have pointed out the two integers where I made a shift mistake... I apologize. I'm catching up myself that it was unconsciously there to make the puzzle harder :p I think you have solved it, haven't you?

Comment: I have to say, it's a bit unfortunate that Jeremy Dover might have had the answer a month ago but for the mistake...

Comment: @boboquack, yes I agree with you. I have totally been sloppy with this puzzle... I apologize to JeremyDover. If you had the answer a month ago, I would feel appropriate to select your answer.

Comment: @boboquack me too, I spotted the nice pattern some time ago but that two items didn't match it so I gave up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Question 1:

> Indigo

Question 2:

> Indigo (or, if the hyphen is not counted in the length, Violet).

Question 3:

> 19

Algorithm used:

> Let $x$ be the number used, and $l$ be its length when written in English (I used "phi" for $\varphi$, "pi" for $\pi$ and "e" for $e$). Then the color is chosen based on $(\lfloor x \rfloor - l) \bmod 7$ by indexing into the colors of the rainbow (0 is Red, 1 is Orange, 2 is Yellow and so on).